# A question about probability theory, convergence in distribution and bounded in probability Thanks!

Tags: probability, statistics, convergence-divergence

[This is the question,please click it to see the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3Uzv.png)

My question is in the picture above(click the link). if we know (A.10), we want to prove convergence in distribution below, why we need to prove the last line. The last line seems to be bounded in probability or uniformly tightness, it implies a subsequence converge in distribution, how to prove this subsequence is the whole sequence and it converge to standard normal like the result in this picture. Thanks!!!

PS. could we use convergence in total variation which is equivalent to convergence in density which is (A.10) to show convergence in distribution (weeker than convergence in TV)

This question is about the asymptotic normality proof. THX any ideas?

Comment: out of curiosity: where comes this from (could you provide a source) and what are the $J_n$ in this context?

Comment: You can regard Jn is a positive definite matrix or fisher information matrix~ Thanks!